# For Loop starting from 0001 instead of 1

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I'm doing a for loop to count from 0001 up to 0999

How can i do this with php. All i've got so far is a normal php for loop.

Comment: Are you trying to echo the values 0001 to 0999?, if so use a normal for loop but sprintf() to format the values when you echo

Comment: Please be more clear what you're looking for. Are you just trying to get leading zeros?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for($i = 1; $i<=999; $i++){
    echo str_pad($i, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Additionally, you can make use of `sprintf()` instead of `str_pad()`, but I think `str_pad()` looks much clearer than `sprintf()` in this case.

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do is a normal loop and format the output:

```
for( $i=1; $i<=999; $i++) {  
  $myformat = str_pad($i, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);         
  // do something with $myformat
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try that code:

```
for($n=1;$n<=999;$n++)
{
    $formatted_n = str_pad($n, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    // add some code here
}
```

[Documentation for `str_pad`](http://php.net/str_pad)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

for($i=1; $i<=999; $i++) {
 echo str_pad($i, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using `sprintf()`:

```
foreach (range(1, 999) as $i){
  echo sprintf("%04d", $i); 
} // output: 000100020003...
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.